# How to send multiple values to Datasnap server using Postman

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I have two methods in my Datasnap server. The first one accepts a `JsonObject`.

### 1º Method - Works

```
function TServerMethods1.UpdateImagem(JsonObj: TJSONObject): Boolean;
```

To send data to `UpdateImagem` I make a `POST` in Postman and send a `raw`.

```
{
    "nome":"soon",
    "tipofoto":"foto"
}
```

The `JsonObj` successfully get in the datasnap server and I can obtain `JsonObj.GetValue('nome')` and `JsonObj.GetValue('tipofoto').Value` .

### 2º Method - Doesn't work

Instead of receiving a `JsonObj`, the second method receives 4 values.

```
function TServerMethods1.UpdateFile(const AArquivo, Pasta: String; Size: Int64;
  const ASetStream: TStream): boolean;
```

I can not send the data to this method. (For now, I am ignoring ASetStream value because I can not even send the others).

**1º Attempt -** I've tried to send as JSON.

```
{
    "AArquivo":"soon",
    "Pasta":"foto",
    "Size":"0"
}
```

This returns me the error: `Cannot convert JSON value {"AArquivo"...} input into TDBXTypes.WideString`.

**2º Attempt -** I've tried to send it as `form-data` and `form-urlencoded`, both me gives the same error: `Message content is not a valid JSON value`.

Any way to send those values?

**Obs:** I can not change the server method because I am not the one who works in the server.

Comment: Is there a working client? In this case, you may inspect the HTTP traffic to see the expected request format.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Use a packet sniffer (Wireshark) or a HTTP proxy (Fiddler2)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data in fact is invalid.

```
{
    "AArquivo":"soon",
    "Pasta":"foto"
    "Size":"0"
}
```

is missing a comma...

```
{
    "AArquivo":"soon",
    "Pasta":"foto",
    "Size":"0"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed the comma in the answer. I used this in Postman, it gives the same error